# android: how to quit the app properly on error

Tags: android, exception

I added an exceptionhandler for unhandled exceptions, to know that the app has crashed on the next app start:

```
@Override
public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("crashed", "yes");
    editor.commit();
}
```

I added the handler via:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);
```

Now the thing is: since I added the handler, the app behaves differently on error:

- Before I added the handler I got a popup telling me that the app has crashed.
- Now, after adding the handler the app just freezes, and after a while android shows me a popup telling me that the app does not respond anymore and whether I want to wait any longer. This is not good IMO. Any hints, how to properly exit after an application crash?

Comment: From an activity to exit you just just call `finish()`.

Comment: @Styx if I call finish() in my error handler, no popup at all shows up. That's not what I was intending either.

Answer (score 5):

you can save the original exception handler , so that you can call it after you are done with doing your own custom operations on the unhandled exception . something like this:

```
//Inside UncaughtExceptionHandler.java:
…
private UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH;

public DefaultExceptionHandler() 
  {
  this.defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
  }

@Override
public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) 
  {
  //do anything you wish about the Throwable e :getStackTrace(),getCause(),getClass()...
  //call the original uncaught exception handler:
  defaultUEH.uncaughtException(t, e);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you integrate your logic with [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/), so that it can handle the issues of crash reporting and cleanup.

Comment: I'm already using Crittercism, which does a great job, but the Crittercism.didCrashOnLastAppLoad() method seems to be buggy...